# IE 11 Appcrash mshtml.dll for 11.0.9600.17842 (Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise)

Tags: internet-explorer-11, hp-uft, crash

I am using IE11 in Windows 2008 R2. While running the UFT Scripts, I am getting the below error whenever a new IE window tries to open along with the Web application. It was working fine couple of months back with no issues. Even I tried uninstalling and re-installing the older version of IE11, still the issue exists.

Please do give some suggestions to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Problem signature:

```
 Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
  Application Name: IEXPLORE.EXE
  Application Version:  11.0.9600.17840
  Application Timestamp:    555fe1bb
  Fault Module Name:    MSHTML.dll
  Fault Module Version: 11.0.9600.17842
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5565cf99
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00291494
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
```